# Correct data structure Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, relation

I currently have this structure for example:

[image]

In this example, you can see that it would be possible to bind multiple users, to one book or more.

Problem I am expierincing is as follows:

There's only 1 main owner of a book. The users that get bind afterwards need to have certain permissions, like edit, delete etcetera. What would be a correct way of dealing this in this structure I am providing? Would I need to store the permissions in the pivot table user_book, or have a seperate table?

Comment: You could either store it in the pivot table or in some global roles/permissions system.

Answer (score 2):

### Here is an abstract idea:

The `Book` table may contain a field for owner as `owner_id` (or `user_id`) so in this case you can create a `one-to-one` relationship for book and it's owner. The method for relationship in `Book` model might look like:

```
public function owner()
{
    // Book belongs to one owner (User)
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'owner_id', 'id');
}
```

So, `$book->owner` will return the owner/user who owns the book. The `owner_id` needs to be set when creating a book. The reverse relation would be `one-to-many` so in `User` model you need to create the `books` method for example:

```
public function books()
{
    // User has many books
    return $this->hasMany('App\Book', 'owner_id', 'id');
}
```

So, from the `User` model you can call:

```
$books = User::find(1)->books; // User::with('books')->find(1);
```

So far the owner and book relationship has been declared. Now for users with permissions you may need to create `many-to-many` relationship between `User` and `Book` model using a pivot table (your current structure), for example:

```
users -> book_user <- books
```

In both models ('User' and 'Book') you need to create method like this:

```
// In Book model
public function permittedUsers() // $book->permittedUsers
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        'App\User',
        'book_user',
        'book_id',
        'user_id'
    )->withPivot('permission');
}

// In User model (books is used for owner)
public function permittedBooks() // $user->permittedBooks
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        'App\Book',
        'book_user',
        'user_id',
        'book_id'
    )->withPivot('permission');
}
```

Your `book_user` table may look like this:

```
id | book_id | user_id | permission
```

Now, when you bind users to books, save the access level in the permission field using the `Unix` system's permission algorithm (similar but not same). For this, at first, create a config file in `config` folder using a unique file name, you may use `book.php` and declare/return the following array:

```
// config/book.php
return [
    'editable' => 1,
    'deletable' => 2,
    'all' => 3
];
```

The Algorithm:

```
if permission value == 1 then user can edit the book
if permission value == 2 then user can delete the book
if permission value == 3 then user can do both (1+2=3)
```

So, when you bind the `users <-> Books` by saving `book_id` & `user_id` in the `book_user` pivot table, also save the permission level in permission field. To achieve this, you may use check boxes and set the value of check boxes as permission's value, for example;

```
<input name="permission[]" type="checkbox" value=1 /> Edit
<input name="permission[]" type="checkbox" value=2 /> Delete
```

When submitting the form, just check if the `permission` was set and then sum/addition the values like:

```
// if(isset('permission'))
if($permission = Request::get('permission')) {
    $permissionLevel = array_sum($permission);
}

// otherwise invalid data, at least 1 permission must be given
```

Save the pivot data including `$permissionLevel` in pivot table. So, when you need to check `Book`'s permissions for a user, you may check if the permission field matches some value in the book_permission table. So as a result you can check easily using something like this:

```
if($user->permittedBooks->first()->pivot->permission == config('book.edit')) {
    // Can edit the book
}

if($user->permittedBooks->first()->pivot->permission == config('book.all')) {
    // Can do everything
}
```

That's all and it's an idea. There could be other ways. You may also check [this article](http://heera.it/laravel-5-1-x-acl-middleware) to get another idea, which is about system wise `ACL` but could be helpfull. You may also check [Unix Permissions Calculator](http://permissions-calculator.org/).